# How do I stack buttons on top of each other

Tags: javascript, html, css

In a project that I'm currently working on, I need to stack several buttons on top of each other. The way that I want to stack them is so that there is no gap in between them. This is what I currently have:

[image: Several rows of black rectangles separated by 5px of white space.]

This is what I want:

[image: A solid black block.]

Is there a way to do this in CSS?

The code that I am using is a function which takes in a height and a width and makes a grid of buttons.

```js
function createBoard (height, width)
{
    for (let h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        for (let w = 0; w < width; w++)
        {
            let button = document.createElement('button');
            button.setAttribute('class', 'pixel');
            document.body.appendChild(button)
            if (w == width - 1)
            {
                let br = document.createElement('br');
                document.body.appendChild(br)
            }
        }
    }
}

createBoard(5,10);
```

```css
.pixel {
    margin:0;
    background-color: rgb(31, 31, 31);
    padding: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    border: none;
}

.pixel:hover {
    background-color: rgb(73, 73, 73);
}
```

Comment: One solution would be using a table with one row and putting the buttons in the cells.

Comment: Create [Minimal reproductive example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without your code, we cannot tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Would this remove any gaps in between the buttons?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly, buttons have no text at all?

Comment: add the buttons and then style them using css.OR you can use ```div``` as buttons .Upload some demonstrative code so i can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.
I have adjusted your js to create rows of buttons and then those rows are added to container. Both rows and container have `display: flex`.
You could ommit rows but it will be harder to create nice grid.

```js
function createBoard (height, width)
{
    for (let h = 0; h < height; h++) {
        const row = document.createElement('div');
        row.classList.add('row');

        for (let w = 0; w < width; w++) {
            const button = document.createElement('button');
            button.classList.add('pixel');
            row.append(button);
        }

        document.querySelector('.container').append(row);
    }

}
createBoard(10, 10);
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.container .row {
    display: flex;
}

.container .row .pixel {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgb(31, 31, 31);
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
}

.container .row .pixel:hover {
    background-color: rgb(73, 73, 73);
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

other way will be to use `grid`, but you will have to specify width of pixel and use it to create your container grid

```js
function createBoard (height, width)
{
    document.querySelector('.container').style.gridTemplateColumns = 'repeat('+width+', 20px)';
    for (let h = 0; h < height; h++) {
        for (let w = 0; w < width; w++) {
            const button = document.createElement('button');
            button.classList.add('pixel');
            document.querySelector('.container').append(button);
        }
    }

}
createBoard(10, 10);
```

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.container .pixel {
    margin:0;
    background-color: rgb(31, 31, 31);
    display:inline-block;
    border: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.container .pixel:hover {
    background-color: rgb(73, 73, 73);
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS grid for the job:

```js
function createBoard(height, width) {
  const board = document.getElementById('board');
  while (board.lastChild) board.lastChild.remove();
  board.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${width}, min-content)`;
  for (let h = 0; h < height; h++) {
    for (let w = 0; w < width; w++) {
      let button = document.createElement('button');
      button.setAttribute('class', 'pixel');
      board.appendChild(button)
    }
  }
}

createBoard(16,9);
```

```css
.pixel {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(31, 31, 31);
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
}

.pixel:hover {
  background-color: rgb(73, 73, 73);
}

#board {
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```